# Como importar bibliotecas Python que estão em outra hierarquia?

Tags: python

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de diretórios

```
src\
    conectores\
              mysql.py
    bibliotecas
    auxiliares
teste\
    chamarMysql.py
```

Na estrutura acima como posso de dentro do arquivo teste\chamarMysql.py, efetuar uma chamada a uma classe que está em src\conectores\mysql.py?

Answer (score 3):

Para que ele entenda que os outros arquivos são módulos, crie um arquivo `__init__.py` vazio em cada pasta.

Se o que você está executando está na pasta raiz (antes de `src` e `teste`), os `import` ficam algo como:

```
from src.conectores import mysql
mysql.seu_metodo()
```

Se não estiver na pasta raiz, precisará de alguma solução simililar a descrita aqui: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder

Answer (score 0):

Basta colocares na mesma pasta um ficheiro em branco com o nome:

```
__init__.py
```

Por exemplo:

```
src\
    conectores\
              __init__.py
              mysql.py
    bibliotecas
    auxiliares
teste\
    chamarMysql.py
```

Todas as pastas que pertençam ao teu projeto deverão ter o mesmo ficheiro.

Comment: Desculpa a ignorância, mas e no arquivo que estou trabalhando a partir dai coloco só o nome do arquivo sem o .py, como normalmente faço quando os arquivos estão no mesmo diretório?

Comment: @BrunoBermann deves colocar um ficheiro de nome __init__.py em todas as pastas e subpastas do teu projeto python.

Comment: Só não entendi como faço o import do arquivo que está um nível abaixo e dentro de outro diretório com subdiretório.

Comment: Como o costume, basta colocares neste caso a linha "import mysql" no ficheiro onde queres importar o módulo. Não precisas de definir a diretoria.